# Add suffix/prefix to single ansible variable

Tags: ansible

I have a file defining ansible variables in `role1/vars/main.yml`, to use in a playbook:

```
app_name: "amazing"
```

And later on I would like to add a suffix to it in another file `role1/vars/over-write-main.yml`:

```
app_name: "{{ app_name }} app"
```

This is part of more a complex project, where `app_name` is defined and then used in a template, to witch I have no access. So the idea was to simply add the suffix to the variable. But I can add a new task, or a new variable file.

However I get a long repetitive error from ansible

```
"AnsibleError: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ app_name}} *.feedzai.live'. 
Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ app_name}} *.feedzai.live'. 
Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '

...

Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: recursive loop detected in template string: {{ app_name }} app"
```

I found a lot of explanations on how to do this to a list, but not to a single variable. Do I need to convert it to a list and then convert it back?

I also tried without success: `app_name: "{{ app_name + 'app'}"`

Comment: How are you setting it the second time...in another variable file? Using `set_fact`? Something else? Please include in your question sufficient code to reproduce the situation you're asking about; that makes it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks @larsks. Thought that was clear. I'm setting it by using another file. And just realized why that doesn't work, since the variable definition is replaced. So how can I do it?

Comment: Note: even though it probably does not change much in this case, `in an other file` is not clear at all. In an other playbook's `vars` section ? A file included from `vars_file` ? with an `include_vars` task ? a `host_vars` or `group_vars` file ? ... There are a lot of possibilities that will influence [precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) and might lead to totally different answers depending on the exact issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-creating the variable using `set_fact` seems to work just fine:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    app_name: amazing

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        app_name: "{{ app_name }} app"

    - debug:
        var: app_name
```